# Problems connecting to tor control port

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

When first installed I had no issue connecting to the tor network, but once closed and re-opened I encounter an issue where it delays while connecting and I recieve a message saying tor cannot connect to control port. It was fine couple weeks ago before the 6.5 update, any quick solutions or this is just a bug? I'm running windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: I'd suspect antivirus/firewall/"security" software interference.

Comment: Seems like that's not the case since I've tried it unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

use standalone Tor for all the controlport activities: Tor Browser Bundle erases settings including auth ones

Comment: Standalone tor? Is that a different version unlike the bundle? If so where can i download it.

Comment: it's called an "expert bundle". If you have downloaded Tor Browser Bundle - you already have a standalone binary - check the install directory for `tor` or `tor.exe` respectively to your platform